# Configure multiple controllers in Spring MVC, and call one controller's method from another controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to configure multiple controller in my application and also trying to redirect from one controller to other.

**Error:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'nc' bean method.

**EDIT :**

**First Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/nc")
public class StockController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testMap", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectToStockList(@RequestParam(value = "testInput") String testInput) {
      System.out.println("In StockController..!!");
      return "SampleTamplate";
 }
}
```

**Second Controller**

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
@Autowired
private UsersServiceImpl    serviceImpl;
private String              redirectedURL;

private static final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory
                                            .getLogger(WelcomeController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username) {
    logger.debug("In login() method.");
    System.out.println("In WelcomeController..!!");
    return "Login";
 }
}
```

**jsp:**

*First Form:*

```
<form action="testMap" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="testInput"/>
</form>
```

*Second Form:*

```
<form action="login" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"/>
</form>
```

When I submit both forms one by one, control goes to 'WelcomeController' every time. And for first form, It gives 'resources not found' error that's OK because there is no mapping present as "/testMap" in welcome controller.

So what I want is, to call specific controller on my form submission and also call one controller's method from another controller.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer this question in both Grails and Spring way as this is the best time to introduce Grails here.

In spring when call is leaving from controller then RequestDispatcher actually helps to catch the call or to check the exact view resolver. Now, as you want to transfer call to another controller here sping provides API (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-redirecting) Inshort you have to use view name like "forward:controllerName" like

```
@RequestMapping({"/someurl"})
public String execute(Model model) {
    if (someCondition) {
        return "forward:/someUrlA";
    } else {
        return "forward:/someUrlB";
    }
```

In grails there is forward method you can find in controller API which does things for you (http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/ControllersApi.html). It actually passes the same session to next requested controller.

Request you to please try to use it. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

In the below example the LoginController redirects to the **/menu** URL if there are validation errors upon submitting a login form by calling the *menuMapping()* method that resides within the MenuController class.

(NOTE: I have included the use of the **BindingResult** class and a hypothetical form as this would be a valid reason for wanting to redirect to another controller. However, below solution would still work as well without the BindingResult and if statement without the use of a form).

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

  MenuController menuController;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
  public String loginMapping(BindingResult result){
     if(result.hasErrors) {
        return "login";
     }
     else {
       return menuController.menuMapping();
     }
}
```

With your MenuController in another class like so:

```
@Controller
public class MenuController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/menu")
  public String menuMapping(){
      return "menu";
    }
}
```

(EDIT: if you wanted to apply the redirect and the controller methods were within the same class then the loginMapping return statement would simply be `return menuMapping();` rather than `return menuController.menuMapping();`